# What is the best method/mic to only capture front sound?

Tags: microphone, microphone-positioning, microphone-technique

We are an events streaming company. We stream with motorbikes and such. We would like to also stream the sound around the motorbike because in sports events people cheers runners and that's cool to hear.

The problem is that the camera guy in the motorbike and the guy controlling the cameras are in constant communication, so simply adding a mic won't work because all the camera chat is also streamed, so we thought in adding 2 directional mics in the motorbike: one at each side (or simply 1 mic at the back, whatever), but the idea is to use a mic that "blocks" sounds in it's back, so camera chatting is not streamed.

Now, how is this reliable? A directional mic truly blocks the sound around it and only captures sound in front of it or simply reduces a bit the db but is still heard? We are a low budget company (just started) and can't start buying expensive mics and do testing just for nothing, so we prefer to ask professionals first.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need 2 mics which are [Cardioid](http://www.harmonycentral.com/forum/filedata/fetch?id=31129488&d=1398382724). That means they mostly record the sound only in front of them. Otherwise you can usea shotgun mic.
Hope this answer is helpfully.

Comment: And will they cancel the cameraman voice by 100%?

Comment: Not by 100% but you can clearly hear the difference. If you only want the sound of the motorbike you'll need a mic in the exhaust or something like that :D

Comment: No no, I want the audio around the motorbike, not the exhaust haha. I think that I will have to force the cameraman to have a full integral helmet when adding cardioid mics.

Comment: Pretty much nothing in audio is 100%, unless you mean 100% not doing anything when the power is turned off.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Hm, I understand. So, I would like to have it as low as it does not get noticed.